# SMS-регистрация на сайте

Tags: php, sms

Всем привет.

Решил попробовать сделать регистрацию на сайте с помощью SMS, но пока что плохо представляю инструменты для решения. Человек указывает свой телефон, а ему на телефон приходит код с подтверждением.

Какие сайты для этого используют? Дорого ли это?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого должна быть высокая посещаемость сайта. Это делается большинством фирм за процент от заработка на ваших смс.
Что-то вроде [smstraffic](http://www.smstraffic.ru/) или [mobilvest](http://www.mobilvest.ru/).

Answer (score 2):

Еще есть [SMSC.RU](http://smsc.ru). У них довольно-таки простое и понятное API, как раз то что Вам нужно.